# Doesn’t <asp:A runat=”server” B=”someValue” … /> syntax violate one of the basic rules in C# language?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Assuming server control of `type A` has a protected `member M`, then we are also able to access `A.M` via declaring `control tag A` on some aspx page:

```
<asp:A runat=”server” M=”someValue” … />
```

But isn’t one of the rules in C#  that protected members of `class A` can only be accessed from `A` and from classes derived from `A`? So doesn’t the ability to access member `A.M` via `<asp:A M=”someValue” … />` syntax violate this rule, since we are basically accessing `A.M` from a class ( which is automatically generated aspx class ) not derived from `A`?!

Comment: In the markup, you're setting B, not M...

Comment: I edited your question. I think you meant `M="someValue"`, otherwise your question doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Why do you think you're accessing from a class not derived from A?

Comment: Darn it, I made a type.I meant M and not B.I will correct it!

Comment: "Why do you think you're accessing from a class not derived from A?" As far as I know aspx page is not derived from A?!

Comment: Oh, you're pointing out that the page and the custom control does not share the same class hierarchy, yet the page can access the controls members.

Comment: "Oh, you're pointing out that the page and the custom control does not share the same class hierarchy, yet the page can access the controls members." Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup cannot touch a protected property. I just tested this:

```
<cc1:ServerControl1 ID="ServerControl11" runat="server" Text="Text Set"
     ProtectedText="foo" />

protected string ProtectedText { get; set; }

protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    output.Write(Text);
    output.Write(ProtectedText);
}
```

This does not display "foo". The property is never modified.

If you set the page to Debug="true":

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ... Debug="true" %>
```

then the C# files that ASP.NET turns your markup into will be left on disk under C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files. It will take some hunting to find the right directory, but here's what I saw for that markup:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
private global::ServerControl1.ServerControl1 @__BuildControlServerControl11() {
    global::ServerControl1.ServerControl1 @__ctrl;

    #line 15 "C:\Documents and Settings\jsaunder\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SOSoln\WebApplication1\Default.aspx"
    @__ctrl = new global::ServerControl1.ServerControl1();

    #line default
    #line hidden
    this.ServerControl11 = @__ctrl;
    @__ctrl.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this);

    #line 15 "C:\Documents and Settings\jsaunder\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SOSoln\WebApplication1\Default.aspx"
    @__ctrl.ID = "ServerControl11";

    #line default
    #line hidden

    #line 15 "C:\Documents and Settings\jsaunder\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SOSoln\WebApplication1\Default.aspx"
    @__ctrl.Text = "Text Set";

    #line default
    #line hidden

    #line 15 "C:\Documents and Settings\jsaunder\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SOSoln\WebApplication1\Default.aspx"
    ((System.Web.UI.IAttributeAccessor)(@__ctrl)).SetAttribute("ProtectedText", "foo");

    #line default
    #line hidden
    return @__ctrl;
}
```

Note what happened to my "foo".

Comment: Uhm, so we are allowed to access protected property from a aspx markup, but the value set via markup won't actually be assigned to protected property?! Then what's the point of being able to a access this property from a markup, if we can't do anything to it?

Comment: @AspOnMyNet: you are not accessing the protected property. You'd have the same effect if you used "FooBar" as the property name. It's only going to pass the "property" name and value to the control for use as extra attributes on the generated markup.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't understood how `<asp:A B=”someValue”` is related to A.M in sentence "o doesn’t the ability to access member A.M via ".

Although i didn't fully understood your post i can tell you: "Don't worry!". Asp.net will never let your violate c# rules because this xml/html like notation is then translated into C# itself.

Answer (score 2):

This only holds if the member you're
setting is not public. Otherwise, you'd never be able to set any properties on any object from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking, is why are protected properties exposed when working with a control in the page markup.

Try this: mark a `Property` on a `custom control` or `user control` as `protected`. What you'll find is you can set its value in the markup, but not the page code-behind. This is the expected behavior. When you edit property values of a control in markup, this isn't violating any visibility/accessibility rules IMO. You are editing the properties of a control within the control in essence. If you mark the Property as `private`, you'll find you can't even edit in markup as expected.

If you then move to the code-behind of your page, and try to change or access the same `protected` property, you'll find it isn't visible. This is because you are trying to access the property from 'outside' the control (from the page class), and the protected rule is enforced.

Hope this helps clarify. I think what you need to consider is in your markup, changes to control properties are considered 'within' the control since they are within the markup of that control. Hard to explain but I think I hopefully made my point...

Comment: "I think what you're asking, is why are protected properties exposed when working with a control in the page markup." Yes. But as it turns out, even though we are able to access this property via markup, the value set in the markup won't actually get assigned to protected property

Comment: @AspOnMyNet good point. I didn't realize this but it is true. I wonder why even expose protected properties to intellisense then..

Answer (score 1):

Control Properties accessed from the calling Page object need to have the public access specifier.

See [Properties, Methods, and Events for Custom Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55x2e446%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> Adding properties and methods is easy
>   — a method is any public procedure you
>   declare in your control class; a
>   property can be declared using a
>   Property  statement in Visual Basic,
>   or implemented as a public member
>   variable in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a quick test and I **wasn't** able to access a protected member of a server control from a web form.  But I made it public and rebuilt the application and it was accessible, as expected.

Is it possible that you didn't recompile the application after setting the field to `protected`?

Comment: "Is it possible that you didn't recompile the application after setting the field to protected?" When I noticed I can access the protected property from a markup, I didn't actually test whether the value set via markup would actually be assigned to a protected property, since I automatically assumed that it will be(but as it turns out it isn't).